# Different JMS providers in Websphere and JMS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-8

**Way 1 : Third-party messaging provider**

I use Websphere application Server 8.5.5 and I configured the queue by creating
my `JMS provider` as mentioned in the  [link1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/umj_pjmsw.html) and [link2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tmj_instp.html)

(In classpath :where I used fscontext jar and required required ibm jms jars  and ).
`QueueConnectionFactory` with my jms provider.

In application I use jms to put meesages to the queue.

```
  @Resource(lookup = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
  private static QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  @Resource(lookup = "jms/Queue")
  private static Queue queue;

  public void putMessagesToQueue() {                                                                   
  try {
     // create a queue connection
     QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
     ......... 
  } catch(JMSException exp) {
       // Handle this exception
   } finally {      
        if(queueConn != null) {                                                     
             // close the queue connection
            queueConn.close();
        } else {
          System.out.println("Queue connection is null");
        }
   }
```

I get the below exception at line connFactory.createQueueConnection(). I see the sysout in final block is getting printed as "Queue connection is null".

**Exception :**

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create queue connection
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.mapToJMSException(JMSCMUtils.java:140) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:91) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]

getLinkedException()=javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Expected QueueConnectionFactory

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory incompatible with javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.createConnection(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:157) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.<init>(JMSManagedConnection.java:352) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.<init>(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:72) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.GenericJMSManagedQueueConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(GenericJMSManagedQueueConnectionFactory.java:92) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:687) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2160) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1838) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3816) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3092) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:85) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

**Way 2 : WebSphere MQ messaging provider**

I used the same code in application to put messages to queue but with different provider which is (`WebSphere MQ messaging provider` ) and created queue Connection factory with that provider and Queue manager, hostname, port and all details I have added in `QueueConnectionFactory`.

In this case I see I don't see any error and I'm successfully able to write in to the queue.

**Question :**

Why is it not working in way 1? I need to work in way 1 not in way 2.

Comment: Why can't you use the WebSphere MQ messaging provider? That is the supported way to configure WAS access to MQ.

Comment: It is suggested inmy requirement to use the way1 and not to use WebSphere MQ messaging provider. Any idea why it is not working in way1,please??

Comment: So what JMS provider do you want to use? Do you have the JARs for that on the classpath?

Comment: I want to use the one described in way 1 and I also added all the jars in the classpath

Comment: I get that you want to use way 1, but if you are talking to IBM MQ why do you have a requirement to use an unsupported mechanism for doing so rather than a fully supported one?

Comment: @Alasdair, I want to proceed in way1, because I need to create my queue connection factory with the jms provider which uses (.bindings file). in way 2, I need to create Queue Connection factory with WebSphere MQ messaging provider and I need to provide specific QueueManager name , host name, port number and channel etc.

Comment: If I want to proceed in way1, I need to get rid of linked exception ResourceAllocationException

Comment: @Attila Repasi, I need to know the significance of .TAB file location in JMS provider configurations Please?

Comment: @Attila Repasi, can you advise me all the jars to be kept in classpath for websphere MQ.

Comment: I added only providerutil.jar and fscontext.jar. I want to know why I am getting classCastException

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/fscontext.jar.html,  www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsunjndiproviderutiljar.html

Comment: As mentioned in the links, I thought these jars are required to solve JNDI.I will remove and give a try

Comment: If you have questions about IBM MQ Channel Tables, or on .binding file vas WAS console configirations then I would suggest you post them as separate questions.  On StackOverflow you should stick to a one question one answer format.  If removing those jar files solves your question, then please add the detail to your question that you added those two jar files.  I can post a quick Answer based on these comments as well.

Comment: I see now it is working after I Changed the QueueConnectionFactory to ConnectionFactory in both service and was.

Comment: @AlagammalP I posted the details from my comments in an answer.  I also removed my comments since the information is included in the answer.  It is advised that you do the same and move any details found only in the comments into the question.  You can remove the comments that no longer provide additional information.  If you feel my answer has helped please accept it and/or upvote it.

Comment: @AlagammalP, if you appreciated the time I spent to research and write my answer up for you please show it by accepting my answer. This can be done by clicking the "grayed out" check mark to the left of the answer under the down arrow, it will turn green indicating it is accepted. Reputation is gained by both of us, you for accepting and I for having my answer accepted. Having answers accepted is an incentive for people to answer questions. I noticed you have a new question that I'll look at when I get some time today.

Comment: I really appreciate your research and support by spending valuable time. But I couldn't mark it as accepted. Because it worked for me  after I changed the QueueConnectionFactory to ConnectionFactory in both service and WAS config without removing providerutil.jar and fscontext.jar.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from OP @AlagammalP, non-IBM MQ supplied providerutil.jar and fscontext.jar were added to the class path.

WAS (Websphere Application Server) comes with the IBM MQ resource adapter included which includes these.

Remove the non-IBM MQ supplied providerutil.jar and fscontext.jar that were added to the class path as they are causing your issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory incompatible with javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
```